# Passing a coroutine to AbstractEventLoop.call_later

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

The following is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> async def foo(loop, iv):
...     await asyncio.sleep(1, loop=loop)
...     print(f'done: {iv}')
...     
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> loop.call_later(2, foo, loop, 10)
<TimerHandle when=36395.554089349 foo(<_UnixSelecto...e debug=False>, 10) at <input>:1>
>>> loop.run_forever()
```

(Python 3.6)

Basically the `foo()` function has some chained `async` calls, so this method has to be `async` as there is a need to `await` for the chained calls. However this method is triggered after a delay, and when one runs this code, the following problem occurs:

> /usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127: RuntimeWarning: coroutine
>   'foo' was never awaited   self._callback(*self._args)

What is the correct way to handle this `async` call in the `call_later`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`call_later()` only supports callbacks (regular functions); you simply can’t pass in a coroutine.

If you want to delay a coroutine, you have two options; either delay the coroutine by having it sleep at the start, or call [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) from `call_later()`, which *does* take a coroutine and schedules it to run.

use `asyncio.sleep()` at the start of the routine, you can have the loop execute it directly:

```
async def foo(iv):
    # delay start of the work
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    # rest of your coroutine
```

You could easily use a wrapper coroutine to do this:

```
async def await_coro_later(delay, coro, *args, **kwargs):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you use `asyncio.create_task()` (or, for Python 3.6 or older, [`asyncio.ensure_future()`](https://docs.python.org/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future), you can pass *that* to `call_later()`:

```
# create a task for foo(10) later
loop.call_later(2, asyncio.create_task, foo(10))
```

Demo of either technique:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> async def foo(iv, start):
...     await asyncio.sleep(1)
...     offset = asyncio.get_running_loop().time() - start
...     print(f'done ({offset:.3f}s): {iv}')
...
>>> async def await_coro_later(delay, coro, *args, **kwargs):
...     await asyncio.sleep(delay)
...     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
...
>>> async def demo():
...     loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
...     start = loop.time()
...     loop.call_later(2, asyncio.create_task, foo('cb_to_create_task', start))
...     await await_coro_later(5, foo, 'coro_later', start)
...
>>> asyncio.run(demo())
done (3.004s): cb_to_create_task
done (6.006s): coro_later
```

Answer (score 3):

Small addition.

It seems that better way is to use lambda.
Instead of use:
`loop.call_later(2, asyncio.create_task, foo('cb_to_create_task', start))`
use
`loop.call_later(2, lambda: asyncio.create_task(foo('cb_to_create_task', start)))`

It's avoid "*RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ResultCursor.finalize' was never awaited*" if timeout cancellation is used and asyncio debugging is enabled.